# Help with high side MOSFET driver IC configuration

Tags: mosfet, buck, gate-driving

I am building a non-isolated buck converter with a N channel MOSFET(2SK4017), I am using the FAN7382 High and low side gate driver. I just want to verify if my wiring is correct before I construct the circuit. 
[image: schematic from datasheet]

Since I only need the high side output would it be sufficient to ground pins 3, 4 and LO? Do I still need to connect Vcc to the supply?

I will be using a fast recovery diode, Rboot=5 Ohm and Cboot= 100nF.

In my application it will be 12V instead of 15V and the PWM signal driving HIN will have a frequency of 10kHz.

Will this design work?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since I only need the high side output

It is OK to use only the high side output and use a freewheeling diode at the low side. But keep in mind that, a significant amount of losses in Buck Converter occurs on the freewheeling diode. If you use a MOSFET with sufficiently low R<sub>ds,on</sub> resistance on the low side too, there will be less losses.

> would it be sufficient to ground pins 3, 4 and LO

You must always connect the COM pin to the ground, because it is the GND pin of the IC. If you desire to use only high side, you should ground the LIN pin. But never ground the LO pin! It is an active output pin. It might be shorted and damage the IC. Even if it doesn't damage it, there may be a power loss on it.

> Do I still need to connect Vcc to the supply?

Yes, of course. V<sub>cc</sub> is always needed for powering the internal circuitry of the IC, and for boot-strapping the high side.

My suggestions:

- Don't use an electrolytic capacitor for C<sub>1</sub>. They don't respond fast in high frequency circuits. Use a ceramic or film capacitor of at least 10nF; preferably 100nF.
- The rated reverse voltage of D<sub>BOOT</sub> must be more that V<sub>HIGH_SIDE</sub> - V<sub>cc</sub>.
- C<sub>BOOT</sub> should at least be around 100 times the input capacitance of the MOSFET (C<sub>iss</sub>) to be driven, and should be a low ESR (e.g.; film) capacitor.
- The peek current on D<sub>BOOT</sub> will be \$\dfrac{V_{cc}}{R_{BOOT}}\$. Choose R<sub>BOOT</sub> and D<sub>BOOT</sub> accordingly. Lower the value of R<sub>BOOT</sub>, faster the capacitor will charge. The power loss on R<sub>BOOT</sub> is independent of its value.
- C<sub>BOOT</sub> will only see V<sub>cc</sub> on it. No need to buy an high voltage capacitor for it. The high reverse voltage will be on D<sub>BOOT</sub>. Make sure its reverse voltage rating is higher than the high side MOSFET drain voltage.

Comment: Thanks heaps! just one question, how would the freewheeling diode on the low side be connected?

Comment: Its anode will be connected at the power ground, and cathode will be at the same line with the V<sub>s</sub> pin of the driver IC. A Schottky diode will be better; but the best option is to use a MOSFET instead of it. If my answer helped, please give it an up-vote and accept it by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

No the pin 3 that is LIN must be connected to vcc by 10k resistor to deactivate low side.
Also do not connect LO to GND this will work fine.