# Is it possible to only use high side driver of fet driver ic?

Tags: mosfet-driver

Is it possible to only use high side part of IR2103 mosfet driver ic, being fully functional, without adding low side driver external components?

[image: IR2103 datasheet]

Comment: Alternative: Charge pumped high side driver Ltc7001 https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC7001.pdf

Comment: Charge pumped High side driver Mic5021 http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005677A.pdf

Comment: High side driver with internal charge pump Ltc1154 https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1154fc.pdf

Comment: Isolated Half-Bridge Driver
with Integrated High-Side Supply (isolated dc-to-dc converter) Adum5230 https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM5230.pdf

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to only use high side part of IR2103 mosfet driver ic

[image]

You can: -

- Use the bottom only
- The top only
- Both as half a H bridge
- **Not** use both simultaneously (and independently) because of the shoot through protection prevents this (thanks to @StainlessSteelRat for pointing this out): -

[image]

The lower side MOSFET connection is a high impedance with a few nF of capacitance and leaving it open circuit won't cause problems.

Comment: Thx @Andy-aka: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/20218/andy-aka: Difficulty is, that voltage between Vb and Vs is just around Vcc level, but not bootstrapped, with 100nF Ct film capacitor and high speed Schottky diode UF5405 verified, without low side driver. How could I confirm that it is no undervoltage lockout of high side driver or too slow diode or too slow or low input current supply (now ~2.5kHz pwm on Hin)?

Comment: Bootstrapping, if required, needs a decent swing on Vs. If that doesn’t occur then you can still use the upper MOSFET without the bootstrap capacitor but you need to raise Vb above Vcc by the amount of gate drive voltage required.

Comment: So there's only bootstrap voltage rise on Vb if there is grounded (floating levels, e.g. isolated dc-dc converters?) load to high side mosfet (means i could not use a bootstrap circuit of ir2103 for providing high side voltage for several equally driven high side mosfets, if Ct capacity and Vcc input current would be sufficient)?

Comment: I’m trying to piece together what you are asking but without punctuation I’m getting confused. Use shorter sentences please and try and be a tad more coherent. For instance you are bracketing a question within a sentence right at the beginning and this is throwing me off. Why don’t you draw what you think you want?

Comment: Ok, one step prior to understanding a high side driver with mosfet connected: Do I get a voltage rise on Vb through bootstrapping if only components of drawing here (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/128283/help-with-high-side-mosfet-driver-ic-configuration) are connected, without mosfet or load to mosfet? If so, i know my current point of failure, so thanks for Your time, experience and advise.

Comment: No, you need a High side MOSFET and grounding load to be connected AND you need to be driving it up and down continuously for boot strapping to be effective. You can’t have slow on off signals because the bootstrap cap gets discharged.

Comment: @Andyaka Shouldn't this bootstrapping requirement be in the answer instead of comments? Was about to raise a question regarding this 'You can use - the top only'...

Comment: @Huisman well, the question didn’t really ask for that. The MOSFET is still fully functional with or without bootstrapping.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat are you referring to the shoot-through protection?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Thank you for that - I shall amend.